# Realtek 8723 AE not working after graphics driver update (from fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04.3)

Tags: 12.04, installation, wireless, drivers, realtek

So I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04.3 on an MSI GE70 with Nvidia GeForce 765m.
Here's the deal:

1. I install Ubuntu off live-usb, with third party option enabled and automatic updates.
2. When I reboot, blank screen. I manage to set up a connection from the console (`ctrl+alt+F1`), then run the usual:

   apt-get update

   Nvidia purge/reinstall

   install Bumblebee

   apt-get upgrade
3. Then, on second reboot, I can't get the wireless to work. Says no device connected.

I'm pretty sure the apt-get upgrade is the issue here (I don't see why it would be anything else).

Is there a way I can "protect" the wireless drivers when running package commands? the one that ships with the basic 12.04.3 works fine.

Extra details:

The wired connection useless, too.

Wireless: Realtek 8723 AE.

I am reinstalling Ubuntu as I write this to be able to work from plain. I'll update if I run into problems. I'll try to install nvidia drivers without running apt-get upgrade, to see if I can maintain wireless capabilities and drivers.

Still, even if that method works, I'd like to know why I can't upgrade my OS.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

I installed the graphic drivers without doing an `apt-get upgrade`, and hell didn't break loose, wireless still works! The integrated graphics work fine, but I'm still having issues with the discrete GPU. At least, I can do that from the install itself instead of a chrooted session from the livecd.

**Update 2:**

Since I couldn't get bumblebee to work, I bit the bullet and did a `apt-get upgrade`. I then did **service network-manager restart**, wireless didn't break. I then did a reboot, and nope, no more wireless. So, something that got updated broke my driver.

lsmod | grep rtl spits out:

```
rtl8723ae         89950
rtlwifi           81225 1 rtl8723
```

and some other stuff.

Comment: Did the driver load as expected? lsmod | grep rtl

Comment: It seems to be loaded? See update 2 in op.

Comment: Any clues in: dmesg | grep rtl or in: rfkill list all

Comment: dmesg: rtlwifi: Firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723fw_B.bin not available

Comment: rfkill: 
0: hci0: Bluetooth

Comment: Soft/hard blocked: no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require but do not have the needed firmware. With a working wired ethernet connection, please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and let us know if it's working.

If you are unable to connect to the internet, download this file on a USB key or similar: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.79.7_all.deb Drag and drop it from the USB key to your desktop. Open a terminal and do:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.79.7_all.deb
```

Reboot.

Comment: Can't connect to internet. THe ethernet connection is also broken. Will a chroot from livecd work?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Excellent, it worked. For the record, going from a chrooteed liveDC did not work.

Comment: Will I have to run that every time I do an apt-get update?

Comment: No, once the firmware is installed, it's installed. No further action is necessary. I hope you will start a new question and we'll attempt to fix your ethernet.